# Re-training deep learning models multiple times to be able to compare their performance?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

Let us say I have two deep learning models that differ in their hyperparameters and I want to compare their performance to each other (in terms of acc/ROC for example). However, a single value from each model does not give me any way of statistical appraisal (eg acc_1 = 0.82 vs acc_2 = 0.84 does not really say much). Would it make sense then to re-train each of the models, say 20 times, and then use t-test to compare each metric between the two models?

Comment: Thank you, that is a valid point. However - I do not know in advance that performances of the models are different, although hyperparameters are. Would it not be of value that you actually *can* reject the null hypothesis? Of course, the *size* of the difference should be intepreted appropriately - a change of 0.1% in acc does not mean much despite being ever so statistically significant... or am I missing something?

Comment: Suppose the actual difference in the performance criterion is 0.00000001. A large enough sample will lead you to reject the null hypothesis. So what? It is obvious that statistical significance is not the same as practical significance. You get paid for practical significance, so you can just skip the t-test and go directly to the practical question, which is simply to estimate the difference in the performance criterion between the two models. A significance test just doesn't address the question you need to answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I see what you mean about the t-test. That raises another question however - I now have two average accuracies with a standard deviation attached to each. I can simply compare these values in terms of average absolute difference, but I am struggling to see how I can make the comparison more statistically “formal”, if you understand my meaning.